# Why is electrocardiogram abbreviated EKG instead of ECG?

Tags: etymology, acronyms

There is no *K* in *electrocardiogram*.  So why is it often referred to as *EKG* instead of *ECG*?

(*ECG* is an acronym for *electrocardiogram*, and [it appears to be used twice as often in English literature as *EKG*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ecg%2Cekg&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).  The question is why *EKG* is ever used at all.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with using "ECG" for electrocardiogram is that it sounds very similar to "EEG," which is the abbreviation for electroencephalogram.  The former is a graph of heart activity; the latter graphs brain activity.

Then there's the potential acronym collision with the other more recent heart scan: the *echo*cardiogram.  (To avoid confusion that one is never referred to by an acronym at all; it is instead shortened to "echo.")

In order to avoid confusing ECGs with EEGs and echoes we often use the abbreviation for the German spelling of electrocardiogram: **E**lektro**k**ardio**g**ramm.

([Sources for this explanation are plentiful](https://greatapeheartproject.org/projects/ekg/#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20difference%20between,spelling%20(elektrokardiogramm%20%E2%80%93%20EKG).).)

Addendum: This seems to be a practice particular to American English.  [In British English "EKG" is used only about 5% as often as "ECG"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ecg%2Cekg&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3).

Comment: Never heard about EKG, but ECG for the heart, and EEG (Electro-encephalograph) for brain

Comment: https://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/ekg/about/pac-20384983 The Mayo clinic uses both.

Comment: EKG is good etymology. _Electron, kardios,_ and _graphein_ are all Greek words (respectively, 'amber', 'heart,' and 'to write'). Mixing Latin and Greek is like mixing colors without metals in heraldry -- bad practice.

Comment: @JohnLawler I can't recall whether it I heard it on television or in my automobile, after some hyperactive ad for antacid or oleomargarine, or maybe some heteronormative liposuction clinic, but that metadata notwithstanding, my neurotransmitters went hyperactive as a neonate's hearing that fimbriation could be used as a loophole. What sociopaths.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because Einthoven, who developed the first practical ECG, spoke Dutch. In 1924 he was awarded the Nobel Prize in Medicine for his design.